# How to Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#

My Code is as follows:

I am using:

```
date=datatype=date;
time=datatype=time;

private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Client_Attendence where date='" +dateTimePicker1.Value + "'", con);
    DateTime dt1= Convert.ToDateTime((dateTimePicker1.Value));
    DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime((dateTimePicker3.Value));

    SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Client_Attendence where date between '" + dt1+ "'and '"+dt2+"'", con);

    DataTable sd = new DataTable();
    sdf.Fill(sd);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = sd;
    //dataGridView1.Columns["balance"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    //dataGridView1.Columns["enddate"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

}
```

Comment: What is the error? Is it before sql or after sql execution. Explain more to avoid downvotes. Also its good to use sqlParameters like @dt1,@dt2 in sql instead of strings for dates.

Comment: You need to specify the format of the datetime. This can be achieved using `dt1.ToString("format")`. See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). You may also need to specify the date field's format. You might want to compare dates only or date and time up to the milliseconds depending on your specified format.

Comment: @Surjit SD@John It is After Execution while fetching data between two dates    Still shows error in data adapter

Comment: Please edit your question and include this detail. Also write full error message. Add tag SqlServer too in question tags. @SandeshBhoir

Answer (score 0):

Convert the datetime to string first might help

```
dt1.ToShortDateString()
dt2.ToShortDateString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `DateTime` value to `String`,

```
DateTime dt1= Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Error in data-adapter

Answer (score 0):

Few things I must suggest here considering your following query:

```
SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Client_Attendence where date between '" + dt1+ "'and '"+dt2+"'", con);
```

**Fixes** required in above query:

1. Use `[date]` instead of `date`
2. You need a space before `and`.

**Suggestions**

1. Use `SqlParameters` instead of string concatination of dates in sql.
2. Add parameters to `SqlCommand` and pass it to `SqlDataAdapter`.

Suggestion 1 will avoid **Sql Injection** attack.

How to achieve 2? Use this link from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted is a copy/paste, you have no space between dt1 and the word "AND".

```
"select * from Client_Attendence where date between '" + dt1+ "'and '"+dt2+"'"
```

needs to be

```
"select * from Client_Attendence where date between '" + dt1+ "' and '"+dt2+"'"
```

Also double check the format of your datetime objects.  Depending on how they are represented in the strings you may need to define your Convert function more like this:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2009-05-08 14:40:52,531", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

substitute your variable for the actual date and time and change the yyy-MM-dd format to match the format of your input.